# OrgXML + Blender + JMonkey

Tags: java, eclipse, blender

I have a problem with OrgXML and JMonkeyEngine. I created a model in blender. After that I exported it into OrgXML format. And I got few files with extensions: mash.xml, scene, materials and some textures in jpg. I was reading the tutorial from JMonkey site and there is an example on that site:

```
// Load a model from test_data (OgreXML + material + texture)

Spatial ninja = assetManager.loadModel("Models/Ninja/Ninja.mesh.xml");
ninja.scale(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
ninja.rotate(0.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f);
ninja.setLocalTranslation(0.0f, -5.0f, -2.0f);
rootNode.attachChild(ninja);
// You must add a directional light to make the model visible!
DirectionalLight sun = new DirectionalLight();
sun.setDirection(new Vector3f(-0.1f, -0.7f, -1.0f).normalizeLocal());
rootNode.addLight(sun);
```

This is correct for this example. I have a beautifull ninja in Eclipse. But when I try do the same with my model, it doesn't work correctly. I have a red sword (which I created) in space, there aren't any textures. I created assets folder in my project directory, and subfolders "Models" and "Sword". In "Sword" directory I have all files which were exported from blender. Anybody know what I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of stuff I would try.

First you probably want to figure out if it's an export problem in Blender or import problem in jmonkey.
Open the .mesh.xml files and see if there's a bunch of coordinates inside.

Second try importing the .scene with the asset manager instead of .mesh.xml. 
Third, try to convert the .scene to a .j3o file by right clicking on it.

I'm a new jmonkey user an am trying to figure all this stuff out too.